# Setting up a Scripting Dictionary for VB in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

looking for help on this. not super familiar with dictionaries but I heard that this would be a lot faster that what I have made. I have multiple columns (73 columns) that have data in one and the one column following has a text that I want to use to flag the data with a color. Here is what I have now but like I said I think the dictionary would be faster.

The text is Normal, Reportable, Abnormal, Critical

```vb
For Each v In Sheets(1).Range("M2:M" & lastRow)

   If v.Value = "Reportable" Then

      Range("m" & v.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' blue

   ElseIf v.Value = "Abnormal" Then

      Range("m" & v.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 36 ' yellow

   ElseIf v.Value = "Critical" Then

      Range("m" & v.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 38 ' red

   ElseIf v.Value = "Normal" Then

   End If

Next v
```

Looking for someone to help me with this?

Thanks J

Comment: Why not just add conditional formatting?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match the description?

Comment: How many rows would the column M:M have? The many columns do not count if you need to process only one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No huge advantage in using a dictionary here - `Select Case` would be a good fit

```
Dim ci

For Each v In Sheets(1).Range("N2:N" & lastRow)
    Select Case v.Value
       Case "Reportable": ci = 37 'blue
       Case "Abnormal": ci = 36 'yellow
       Case "Critical": ci = 38 'red
       Case Else: ci = xlNone
    End Select
    v.Offset(0, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = ci 'same cell as v ?
Next v
```

Comment: Sorry Tim if I was unclear but Column M has the data I wish to change the color in but the text to tell which case it is appears in Column N.  Reminder I have this same thing for 73 columns and it can range on number of rows.

Comment: @James K: What? Do you check the strings in one column and color the interior of another one? Where did you ask for such an issue? In works or in code, I mean... If you want doing that, is OK but is it a general rule? I mean, checking column A:A, what column will be colored in case of occurrences?

Comment: Simple fix which you could probably have figured out - see edit

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that a dictionary will help. I think the speed will be increased if the interior coloring will be done at once, not cell by cell. That's why, try this code, please:

```
Sub colorInterior()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngB As Range, rngY As Range, rngR As Range
 Dim LastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, i As Long, j As Long
 
  Set sh = Sheets(1)
  LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To lastCol
       If sh.Cells(i, j).Value = "Reportable" Then
            If rngB Is nothint Then
                Set rngB = sh.Cells(i, j)
            Else
                Set rngB = Union(rngB, sh.Cells(i, j))
            End If
       ElseIf sh.Cells(i, j).Value = "Abnormal" Then
            If rngY Is nothint Then
                Set rngY = sh.Cells(i, j) '.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 ' yellow
            Else
                Set rngY = Union(rngY, sh.Cells(i, j))
            End If
       ElseIf sh.Cells(i, j).Value = "Critical" Then
            If rngR Is nothint Then
                Set rngR = sh.Cells(i, j) '.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 ' red
            Else
                Set rngR = Union(rngR, sh.Cells(i, j))
            End If
       ElseIf v.Value = "Normal" Then
            'here you maybe need to set interior like none
       End If
   Next j
 Next i
 rngB.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' blue
 rngY.Interior.ColorIndex = 36 ' yellow
 rngR.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 ' red
End Sub
```

Comment: My rows could be 50-2000 and there are 73 columns to go through.  All the same text values are used (ie Normal, abnormal, reportable and critical).  If it was just one column I wouldn't worry about changing much.

Comment: @James K: But your code goes  only to M:M column... Can you better explain what you really need? Do you need to process in the same way all 73 columns? Are all of them the same number of rows? In order to be faster, you do no have to repeat this code! Using the same union ranges the code will be faster...

Comment: Yup same processing for all 73 columns.  the sample code I added was just a way of explaining where I was at.

Comment: Further example:   Column M has my data (1,2,4,etc) column N has string(normal, abnormal, etc).  I want to flag my data with a color (blue, red, yellow, etc) based on column N text.  I want to process 73 columns in the same fashion in a fast way.

Comment: @James K: But if we do not what you want accomplishing we can not really help. If you want to do the code by yourself, I would suggest you (of course, if the same strings will be the code conditions) to make another loop for the columns and **use the same union ranges** to collect the cells to be specifically colored.

Comment: @James K: Adapted the code to process all existing columns. The code assumes that all columns have the same number of rows. If not, this have to be calculated for each column (each new j)... And the colored cells will be the ones matching your criteria...